# UNIX: cut inside if

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, cut

I have a simple search script, where based on user's options it will search in certain column of a file.

The file looks similar to passwd

```
openvpn:x:990:986:OpenVPN:/etc/openvpn:/sbin/nologin
chrony:x:989:984::/var/lib/chrony:/sbin/nologin
rpcuser:x:29:29:RPC Service User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin
nfsnobody:x:65534:65534:Anonymous NFS User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin
radvd:x:75:75:radvd user:/:/sbin/nologin
```

now the function based on user's option will search in different columns of the file. For example

```
-1 "searchedword" -2 "secondword"
```

will search in the first column for "searchedword" and in the second column for "secondword"
The function looks like this:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -1|--one)
              c=1
              ;;
    -2|--two)
              c=2
              ;;
    -3|--three)
              c=3
          ;;
    ...
  esac
```

In the c variable is the number of the column where I want to search.

```
cat data | if [ "$( cut -f $c -d ':' )" == "$2" ]; then cut -d: -f 1-7 >> result; fi
```

Now I have something like this, where I try to select the right column and compare it to the second option, which is in this case "searchedword" and then copy the whole column into the *result* file. But it doesn't work. It doesn't copy anything into the result file.

Does anyone know where is the problem?
Thanks for answers

(At the end of the script I use:

```
shift
shift
```

to get the next two options)

Comment: From my side of the world, the main problem is that you're using the wrong tool for the job.  Using `cut` throws away all the other fields in the line, so you can't use the output from one operation for the second condition.  This cries out for `awk` in my view: `awk -F: '$1 == "searchedword" && $2 == "secondword"'` would do the job (you'd have the shell script write the `awk` script though).  If you must use `cut`, you have to restructure your shell script to read each line, use `cut` on the line to check each word, and send the output to the results file.  The `if` is mostly wrong.

Comment: You can't pipe things into `if`.  Piping by doing something like `command1 --option arg filename | command2 arg1 arg2` chains the output of the first command and its set of options and arguments to the input of the second.  `if` has no capacity to read from standard input as it's a conditional construct of bash, not a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using awk for this task as awk is better tool for processing delimited columns and rows.

Consider this awk command where we pass search column numbers their corresponding search values in 2 different strings `cols` and `vals` to awk command:

```
awk -v cols='1:3' -v vals='rpcuser:29' 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=":"               # set input/output field separator as :
    nc = split(cols, c, /:/) # split column # by :
    split(vals, v, /:/)      # split values by :
}
{
   p=1                       # initialize p as 1
   for(i=1; i<=nc; i++)      # iterate the search cols/vals and set p=0
      if ($c[i] !~ v[i]) {   # if any match fails
         p=0
         break
      }                      # finally value of p decides if a row is printing or not
} p' file
```

**Output:**

```
rpcuser:x:29:29:RPC Service User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin
```